# Maximizing functions with statements similar but result different

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum, maximize

I would like to know why when I maximize the sum of two functions with similar expressions (Qu and Qm), it gives me different results (nu and nm), since they should be the same results because the values of the parameters have the same value.

```
ku = 1; km = 1; \[Mu] = 10000 ; \[Epsilon]u = 0.0003; \[Epsilon]m = \
0.0003; \[Alpha] = 0.95; \[Lambda]m = 1; \[Lambda]u = 1;
Qu = nu ku E^(\[Epsilon]u (\[Mu] - nm \[Lambda]m - nu \[Lambda]u));
Qm = nm km E^(\[Epsilon]m (\[Mu] - nm \[Lambda]m - nu \[Lambda]u)); 

Maximize[{Qu + Qm, 
  nu >= 0 && nm >= 0 && 
   nu \[Lambda]u + nm \[Lambda]m <= \[Alpha] \[Mu]}, {nu, nm}, Reals]
```

`{24630.2, {nu -> 1233.11, nm -> 2100.22}}`

Someone who can help me and if necessary to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ku = 1;
km = 1;
μ = 10000;
ϵu = 0.0003 // Rationalize;
ϵm = 0.0003 // Rationalize;
α = 0.95 // Rationalize;
λm = 1;
λu = 1;
Qu = nu ku E^(ϵu (μ - nm λm - nu λu));
Qm = nm km E^(ϵm (μ - nm λm - nu λu));
```

The maximum does not occur at a unique `{nm, nu}` point. The maximum is correct at whichever point that is selected provided that the function is maximum. To readily get the exact value let `nm == nu`

```
{max, arg} = 
 Maximize[{Qu + Qm, 
   nu >= 0 && nm >= 0 && nu λu + nm λm <= α μ && 
    nm == nu}, {nu, nm}, Reals]

(* {(10000 E^2)/3, {nu -> 5000/3, nm -> 5000/3}} *)

max // N

(* 24630.2 *)
```

More generally (and not assuming that `nm == nu`),

```
sol = Solve[{D[Qu + Qm, nm] == 0, D[Qu + Qm, nu] == 0, nu >= 0, nm >= 0, 
      nu λu + nm λm <= α μ}, {nu, nm}][[1]] // 
   Simplify // Quiet

(* {nm -> ConditionalExpression[10000/3 - nu, 0 <= nu <= 10000/3]} *)
```

At all of these points, the function value is the maximum

```
max === (Qu + Qm /. sol // Normal // Simplify)

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you too much. I undertand.

Answer (score 0):

The max is not unique. It is atteind for many values of nu and nm. E.g. consider the max you found:

```
Qu+Qm /. {nu -> 1233.109905637882`, nm -> 2100.2234703583167`}

(* 24630.2 *)
```

However, we get the same value e.g. for:

```
Qu + Qm /. {nm -> 1233.109905637882`, nu -> 2100.2234703583167`}

(* 24630.2 *)
```

You get the same value also for nu==nm:

```
c1 = 1233.109905637882`;
c2 = 2100.2234703583167`;
Qu + Qm /. {nu -> (c1 + c2)/2, nm -> (c1 + c2)/2}

(* 24630.2 *)
```

Comment: Thank you too much. I undertand. It was very useful.